# How can I run serialize on all forms with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I tried to write a function that happens on all forms in a page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('form').click(function() {
        alert (this.serialize());
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

but I get the error

> this.serialize is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

### UPDATE

`$(this)` worked

So now I tried:

```
$('form').click(function() {
    alert ($(this).serialize());
    $("input, select, textarea").attr("disabled", true);
    alert ($(this).serialize());
    return false;
});
```

But this disables all elements in **all forms** on the page.

How can I just disable those in the form that submitbutton was pressed?

Comment: `$(this).find("input, select, textarea").attr(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
$(this).serialize();
```

Instead of

```
this.serialize();
```

---

To disable **only** the fields of this form,

```
$('form').click(function () {

    // ...

    $(this).find('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });

    // ...

});
```

Comment: thanks, how stupid, I guess I am still a beginner ;)

Comment: @rubo77 No problem! Remember `$()` is the jQuery constructor function, while `this` is a reference to the DOM element of invocation. So whenever you need a jQuery function surround `this` with `$()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the jQuery object: `$(this).serialize()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering your 2nd question about the disabled.

If you want you can do something like:

```
$('#saveButtonForm3').click(function() {
    alert ($(this).parent().serialize());  // parent() is the form, $(this) is the button
    // this line will disable the fields in the form where the save button is clicked
    $(this).parent().find("input, select, textarea").attr("disabled", true);
    alert ($(this).parent().serialize());
    return false;
});
```